# How to constrain generic to be a type that can be props of a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just finished fighting with the typescript compiler to create a component that takes another component as a prop- and then requires all that components props as props to pass to it. (The use case is for Gatsby `<PrivateRoute>` components).

I've managed to actually get it working, but the problem is I can't figure out why this works.

Here is a simplified example:

The wrapper component and defined props:

```
type WrapperProps<T> = { component: React.ComponentType<T> } & T;

const Wrapper = <T extends object>({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}: WrapperProps<T>) => {
    return <Component {...(rest as T)} />;
};
```

and the intended use:

```
interface person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const ShowPerson = ({ name, age }: person) => {
    return (
        <h1>
            {name}, {age}
        </h1>
    );
};

const Display = () => {
    return <Wrapper component={ShowPerson} name="T" age={12} />;
};
```

The part that I can't figure out *why* its working is in the generic constraint in the wrapper component. If I remove `<T extends object>`, I will get an error "`conversion of type 'Omit<WrapperProps<T>,"component"> to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other`

Now, it makes sense that the generic needs to be constrained, but is there a better constraint than using `<T extends object>` ? Why does `<T extends {}>` not work?  What would be an acceptable and better generic constraint that would work as the props of a React component? `extends object` does not feel like the correct solution to me.

**Edit**
This can also be functional by casting `...rest as unknown as T`, but I'm still struggling to wrap my head around it:

```
const Wrapper = <T,>({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}: WrapperProps<T>) => {
    return <Component {...(rest as unknown as T)} />;
};
```

[Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAdShTBqgAUcwBnAHgBUA%20OAF44AbzhpckAHZJpMAFyJiMAHQBhKRFnze1JH0EBfOADI4vANzlJ0zvAZMWwuHwA0-ABSjScPxK0dRThNcG05GDdff1VYontSIyVHZiQ2Dh4BAEphQR9-OCIYAFcoaVdQmQixWNVPePgUTjhi6QBraQgAd3KmiyyTAHp%20ayNrUmB5NMx0WhZObTFov2kUECQleyhJgHNrApQdjbhpYpAAIzTRm217OABlAAtu1jSF8pFvE7WkNzhD2hJODzbQ5IR5ZaFJAlMpwTyQgrcR4ARn4CIK-lEq3WRj%20ogBRnRfm4gxRaIKWVG41sdwAIsBOGAADYoSguTxgiEFIqlcrcFLOSRhIJCURPF5vbQmbFIIQAIgAcj85f8jqLkQAmIzDKlAA)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492 for the reason `{}` doesn't work, basically it translates to `any non nullish type`. The preferred solution is `Record<string, unknown>` I believe in this case.

Comment: `<T extends Record<string,unknown>>` does not work, but I for sure see where you're coming from.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I'd be more inclined to capture the component as the generic and then infer the props from that. Example: https://tsplay.dev/W48o1W.

Comment: @AlexWayne, this makes it way easier to understand! Thanks!

Comment: @AlexWayne The only issue with this solution is that component is no longer a required prop according to the typescript compiler

Comment: @AlexWayne - Nice one! -- I tried to take that approach yesterday and didn't get as far as you did.